# Ignoring popBackStack() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using the new android Navigation Framework in one of my Applications. The purpose of the Application is to behave as a launcher.

Sometimes when I try to change the fragment (navigate using the nav controller) it doesn't change the fragment instead it logs

Ignoring `navigate()` call: FragmentManager has already saved its state
I know this question been asked before here Ignoring `navigate()` call: `FragmentManager` has already saved its state but it doesn't have a Solution.

I am navigating using the following code:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_next, bundle);
```

Comment: You can't do operations after the state is saved, that's working as intended. Why are you trying to change anything after your Activity has already saved its state and is being destroyed/recreated?

Comment: Because we will maintain a long link, when the application is in the background long link exists, there will be some instructions to do the page jump